# Remove Mod Page Speed module

Tags: whm, mod-pagespeed

I have installed mod page speed Customized module from the bellow reference link on whm centos 5 ,32 bit with Apache 2.2.27.

http://forums.cpanel.net/f402/install-mod_pagespeed-cpanel-using-easyapache-302431.html

But now page speed module giving a warning `" ModPagespeed Generated File Prefix is deprecated please remove configuration"`

so i want to remove that configuration of custom module.

if any body have any idea how to remove it let me know.

i was try bellow command but it is not working for me

```
sudo yum remove mod-pagespeed-stable
```

when i open file using  command `nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf` to add the mod page speed filters  its show this error

```
[ Error writing /etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf: No such file or directory ]
```

so that i want remove this custom page speed module.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided, it doesn't look like you installed mod_pagespeed using an RPM, so the yum command will not work.

If you installed it using WHM and easyapache, then you should be able to go through the web interface and disable the module. You need to disable it first, so that apache does not look for it on startup.

Once it's disabled, you can uninstall it by removing the custom mod files:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Custom+Modules

The files are probably in:

/var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/mod_pagespeed

or similar. It's probabaly best to move them somewhere else first, before deleting them completely.

Comment: i dont want to disable module from easy apache whm i just want remove the module totally from server

Comment: Right, but you'll need to disable it first, otherwise apache will try to find it when it starts up - and will probably not start if it's missing. (Updated answer with more information)